# Vertically Center Dynamic Height Image That is Taller than Parent

Tags: css, responsive-design

I'm working on a fluid/responsive design layout that's supposed to have a fixed-height narrow bar across the bottom with several logos on it. The logos are dynamic height, but will generally be taller than the bar. They need to line up with a column of information on the left, and be vertically centered on the bar. Because it is a fluid/responsive layout, the width of the left column is percentage based, and I am sizing the width of the images to a percentage of the column and allowing their height to adjust automatically. This approach allows the site to fluidly adjust to any screen size, even ones that fall between my responsive breakpoints. (See [example code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/iBzkK).)

I usually use relative positioning and/or negative margin to simulate vertical centering, but that doesn't work well with dynamic height content. Right now my best idea is to set an appropriate position/margin for each of the main breakpoints, and figure it will be "close enough" on screen sizes in between -- but obviously, that's not an ideal solution, as it means the elements will be misaligned to some degree on some screens. (See [example code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Bljki) and adjust browser width up and down.)

Is there any way to get the images to reliably stay vertically centered on the bar as their heights change?

EDIT: Cab suggested a promising option below, but it relies on JavaScript, which should always be a last resort for basic layout. Is there any way to do this without resorting to JavaScript?

Comment: use "display" property in css3, it may solve your problem..!!

Comment: What do you have in mind?

Answer (score 1):

## DEMO: http://jsbin.com/AwipiLe/1/

### EDIT: http://jsbin.com/AwipiLe/1/edit

---

jQuery for col 2 so it clears:

```
var headerheight =  $("col-one").height();

$(window).on('resize load', function() {

   $('.row .col-two').css({"padding-top": 35 + headerheight + "px"});

});
```

HTML

```
<div class="row">  
  
   <div class="col-one"><!--
   --><img src="http://placehold.it/90x60" /><!--
   --><img src="http://placehold.it/90x60" /><!--
   --><img src="http://placehold.it/90x60" /><!--
--><br style="clear:both;">
            
  </div>
  
    <div class="col-two">Lorem ipsum dolor set amet.</div>

       <span></span>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.row {
  width: 100%;
  position:relative;
}

.row span {
  width:100%;
  height:35px;
  background:#ddd;
  display:
  block;position:absolute;
  top:50%;margin-top:-17px;
}

.row .col-one {
  width: 30%;
}

.row .col-one img {
  position:relative;
  z-index:1;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 0 0.5em;
}

.row .col-two {
  width: 68%;
  display:block;
  float:right;
  position:relative;
  z-index:1;
}
```

I'd put this in a min-width and then screw around for before media queries. jQuery affects all sizes so bare that in mind. So you can do max-width media for that area and use !important to over-ride the padding top on the col-two for small sizes.